# Python set unpacking and pattern matching

Tags: python

If this unpacks a set:

```
>>> a = {1,2,3}
>>> (x, y, z) = a
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
3
```

Then why the following doesnt?

```
>>> a = {1,2,3}
>>> match a:
...   case (p, q, r):
...     print(f'{p} {q} {r}')
...
>>>
```

I would expect the code above to print "1 2 3".
I understand how sets aren't ordered and I wouldn't be surprised if both didn't work, but the former works, only the latter doesn't.
I've always thought that pattern matching IS based on unpacking.

This is not about types not matching, because if we replace the set {1,2,3} with a list [1,2,3] it would work even though we unpack with a tuple syntax.

Comment: Did you defned p q and r ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT: There is no need to pre-define those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` statement sequence patterns have more restrictive rules than sequence unpacking. Sequence unpacking will try to unpack any iterable, but a sequence pattern is [specified](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#sequence-patterns) to require

> one of the following:
>
> - a class that inherits from `collections.abc.Sequence`
> - a Python class that has been registered as a `collections.abc.Sequence`
> - a builtin class that has its `Py_TPFLAGS_SEQUENCE` bit set
> - a class that inherits from any of the above (including classes defined *before* a parent’s `Sequence` registration)

`set` doesn't meet any of those conditions.

Note that since sets are semantically unordered, there is no guarantee which elements will be assigned to which variables if you try to unpack a set. Your `(x, y, z) = a` unpacking is not safe.